# Register user to database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, postman, knex.js

i'm trying to insert email using postman and node.js to postgresql. however the email appears like this:

12 | John  |{"email":"john@gmail.com"}

instead of:

12 | John  |john@gmail.com

```
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const { email, name, password } = req.body;

    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password); 
        db.transaction(trx => {
            trx.insert({
                hash: hash, 
                email: email
            })
            .into('login')
            .returning('email')
            .then(loginEmail => {
                return trx('users')
                    .returning('*')
                    .insert({
                        email: loginEmail[0],
                        name: name,
                        joined: new Date()
                    })
                    .then(users => {
                        res.json(users[0]);
                    })
            })
            .then(trx.commit)
            .catch(trx.rollback)
        })

    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to register'))
})
```

Comment: When you debug, what is the observed runtime value of `email` in the request body?  In the browser's debugging tools, when the request is made, what is the request body?  If `email` is an object, do you *want* or *expect* it to be an object in the request, or do you want it to be a string instead?  Are you looking to receive an object server-side and only use a property on that object, or are you looking to only send a string from the client instead of an object?  The issue itself seems clear, but what change you're looking to make isn't.

Comment: Or, conversely, is the *second* `.insert()` operation the issue?  Which specific operation are you asking about here?  Is `loginEmail[0]` the object?  Do you expect it to be?  What data is returned by that first operation and how does it differ from what you expect?  The question needs more details.

Comment: I'm trying to post an email which should enter the users database as an email which is a string. fro example i want my postgre database to have user and his email as john@gmail.com instead of what i'm receiving at the moment in my postgre database: {"email":"john@gmail.com"}

Comment: There are two `.insert()` operations in the code shown.  Which one are you referring to?

Comment: This is what my database looks like at the moment:
              
  8 | Amy    | theamy@gmail.com ,                   
 11 | John   | {"{\"email\":\"john@gmail.com\"}"} ,
 12 | Enn    | {"email":"enn@gmail.com"} ,        
 13 | johnny | {"email":"john1@gmail.com"} ,     
(7 rows)

Comment: If you don't know which operation you're referring to then I guess the next step is to *make guesses*.  What happens if you replace `loginEmail[0]` with `loginEmail[0].email` ?

Comment: `joined` is in your code, but missing in the database. At least in your examples.

Comment: @David this worked. I'm not sure what the code did but works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to clarify and clean up your code for you a bit :)

```
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const { email, name, password } = req.body;

    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password); 
        db.transaction(trx => {
            trx.insert({
                hash, // Note that you dont need do to hash: hash
                email,
            })
            .into('login')
            .returning('email')
            .then(loginEmail => {
                return trx('users')
                    .returning('*')
                    .insert({
                        email: loginEmail[0].email,
                        name,
                        joined: new Date(),
                    })
                    .then(users => {
                        res.json(users[0]);
                    })
            })
            .then(trx.commit)
            .catch(trx.rollback)
        })

    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to register'))
})
```

A whole **other way** of doing this (in order to **avoid this callback-hell**) is with async/await like this:

```
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const { email, name, password } = req.body;

    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password); 
    let trx;
    try {
       trx = await db.transaction();
       const loginEmail = await db.into('login')
                         .insert({
                                hash,
                                email,
                         })
                         .returning('email')
                         .transacting(trx);
       const users = await await db.into('users')
                         .insert({
                                email: loginEmail[0].email,
                                name,
                                joined: new Date(),
                         })
                         .returning('*')
                         .transacting(trx);
       await trx.commit();
     } catch (error) {
         if (trx) { 
            await trx.rollback();
         }
         // Insert some logging here maybe
         res.status(400).json('unable to register'))
      
    }  
})
```